# Exchange Server Login Credentials Setup

Tags: c#, exchange-server-2007, webmail

I just want to pass this by you and make sure that I am doing this right. My code:

```
ExchangeService _mailService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
_mailService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(@"userName", @"password", @"mydomainInfo");
//_mailService.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
_mailService.Url = new Uri("https://webmail.mydomain.com/ews/exchange.asmx");

try
{
    ItemView allItems = new ItemView(100);
    SearchFilter searchFilterInbox = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false);
    Folder _inbox = Folder.Bind(_mailService, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
// <SNIP>
```

So I get this far and the Bind returns an Authentication Fail (401). If I comment out the '.Credentials' and uncomment '.UseDefaultCredentials', I log in just fine. But I need to access a different inbox folder. I pulled the UserName and Domain Name from my account on Outlook. Even if I use my own login information, I still get this error. To me that says I'm just not providing the right information. Thoughts? I can log into the web side of the service just fine.

Comment: I guess a good question would be is this trying to access the Exchange server via the web client or the server client? The username is different depending on which one I'm logging in to. I'm sure the domain would be too. I think I've tried every combination I can think of but nothing is working....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I solved my own problem. It was what I was suspecting. I just didn't have the correct data in the "domain" and "username" fields. I was actually calling the server the Exchange Server was on. So I changed it to the domain that my computer is logged into and changed the user id from "me@email.com" to "me" and it works! So I had it all setup right, just wrong information.